# Why does my JavaScript RegExp not work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing a password screen, and the requirements for the password security are somewhere between 8 and 20 characters in length, must contain *at least* one Alpha character and *at least* one numeric character and *at least* one special character of `[!@#$%^&*]`.

I have cobbled together this regular expression, which appeared to work in C#, but when I started rewriting the code for a JavaScript validation, the regular expression is flagging what I thought were valid passwords as invalid.

Here is the regular expression as I assign it to RegExp:

```
var regExPatt = new RegExp('^(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){1})(?=(?:.*\d){1})(?=(?:.*[!@@#$%^&*]){1})(?!.*\s).{8,20}$');
```

**NOTE BENE:** The double `@@` symbol is there to get the `@` symbol into the RegExp, otherwise it tries to treat partial strings like Razor variables and things go sideways fast.

Where did I go wrong with this regular expression? I know it is fairly complicated.

Passwords that work:

```
freddy1234%
freddy123$5
freddy12#45
freddy1@345
freddy!2345
```

Passwords that do not work:

```
test1234%
wilma1234%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So, this wouldn't allow for a space, round parentheses, (semi-)colon, pipe, question mark, angle brackets, dash, underscore, equals, plus, slashes, period, comma, or tilde? That could frustrate some users as it definitely seems most of these are symbols. Considering how little time/effort it would take to iterate over the string, I'd do that instead of a restricting regex.

Comment: That is correct Corey.  I could maybe talk the users into allowing those characters.  However, I still do not understand why freddy* works and wilma* does not.  Any ideas there?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting assistance, Biffen.

Comment: @user3669641 Is regex rendered right in html code? Can you check the source code of page in browser?

Comment: [relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: I just had a comment that explained it, I think.  JavaScript does not allow the look around syntax.  Which the above regular expression is built on.  I just split this out into 4 different regular expressions and set it up to get around the situation.  Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript developers should have knowledge about

- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object description
- [Regular Expressions chapter in the JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Developers who want to use positive or negtive lookahead should take into account that this requires JavaScript v1.5 as it can be read on page [New in JavaScript 1.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.5). But that should be no problem nowadays as this is a very old version released on November 2000 and all browsers used nowadays support v1.5 of JavaScript.

Lookbehind is not yet (JavaScript v1.8.5) supported by JavaScript at all.

A list of the JavaScript versions and which browser supports which JavaScript version can be found on Wikipedia page about [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

[New in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript) contains the links to the pages explaining what was added in which version of JavaScript.